# How can I echo attribute name On-Click or hover in Magento product view page

Tags: magento, attributes, custom-attributes

I installed a module that gave me color swatches as a thumbnail instead of dropdown. How can I echo the attribute (color) name once a user has clicked on the color?

For example, if they click the Black thumbnail, I would like the phrase "Color:Black" to display below. Can anyone help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What version of magento are you using? also what is the module. Im guessing you want to use javascript to populate a span or something underneath the color swatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your color swatches have a "selected" state, you may trivially be able to use that for styling. For instance:

```
<a class='color' href='#'><img src='path/to/red.png' /><span class='label'>Red</span></a>
<a class='color' href='#'><img src='path/to/green.png' /><span class='label'>Green</span></a>
<a class='color selected' href='#'><img src='path/to/blue.png' /><span class='label'>Blue</span></a>
```

And accompanying CSS:

```
.color .label { display:none; }
.color.selected .label { display:block; }
```